# Python cachetools sharing memory in a multicore server

Tags: python, nginx, multicore

I'm using python cachetools to cache responses from a remote service. While running the service locally, the following code produces expected results: it calls the external service the first time, and all subsequent requests are served out of the cache.

```
@staticmethod
@cached(cache=TTLCache(maxsize=10000, ttl=3600))
def func_cache_test(param1, param2):
    var1 = call_external_func(param1, param2)
    return var1
```

However, when I run the code on a server(nginx) with multiple cores, it seems to be spinning up a process for each core. Since we have 8 cores on the server, it seems like the program is making up to 8 remote service calls.

I'm not using multi-threading or multi-processing. How do I get all cores(and processes) on the server to share a single cache so I can take full advantage of caching?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: There's this file-based extension to cachetools that might work: https://github.com/olirice/cachetools_ext. You might still run into an issue with locks if the processes are trying to access the file at the same time